# Filtering on JSON internal keys stored in PostgreSQL table

Tags: json, postgresql, filter

I have a report in JSON format stored in a field in a PostgreSQL database table.
Say the (simplified) table format is:

```
      Column       |            Type
-------------------+----------------------------
 id                | integer
 element_id        | character varying(256)
 report            | json
```

and the structure of the data in the reports is like this

```
{
  "section1":
    "test1": {
      "outcome": "nominal",
      "results": {
        "value1": 34.,
        "value2": 56.
      }
    },
    "test2": {
      "outcome": "warning",
      "results": {
        "avg": 4.5,
        "std": 21.
      }
    },
    ...
  "sectionN": {
    ...
  }      
}
```

That is, there are N keys at first level (the *sections*), each of them being an object with a set of keys (the *tests*), with a *outcome* and a variable set of *results* in form of `(key, value)` pairs.

I need to do filtering based on internal JSON keys.  More specifically, in this example, I want to know if it is possible, using SQL alone, to obtain the elements that have, for example, the `std` value in the *results* section above a certain threshold, say 10. I can even know that the `std` is in `test2`, but I do not know *a priori* in which section. With this filter (`test2.std > 10.`), for example, the record with the sample data shown above will appear, since the `std` variable in the `test2` test has this value equal to 21. (>10.).

Another, simpler, filter could be to request all the records for which the `test2.outcome` is not `nominal`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is `jsonb_each`, like:

```
select  section.key
,       test.key
from    t1
cross join
        jsonb_each(t1.col1) section
cross join
        jsonb_each(section.value) test
where   (test.value->'results'->>'std')::int > 10
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/49397/15/0)

Comment: Wow, I was not aware of this possibility, made it really made my day!  The example is simpler than what I have in reality, but your solution is scalable enough, and... I tested and it works!